# Tkinter frame not showing on button click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to develop a school app in tkinter. I am creating a frame for each tab in the app. I have included my tabs as pages in the code. I have created the UI for each tab. It works perfectly fine when run individually.

I tried to combine it by stacking the frames.

I am having no error but the tkinter frame corresponding to the 'Home' in the app is not loading.

Any help is appreciated.

```
class SchoolApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("1500x750")

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self,width=200,height=50,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        main_frame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='True')

        main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {}
        pages = (Home,HomePage,LogIn,AdminPage,StaffPage,AdminAddStaff,AdminRemoveStaff,AdminSelectStaff,AdminSearchStaff,AdminUpdateStaff,StaffAddDetails,StaffDisplyDetails)
        for F in pages:
            frame = F(main_frame, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.pack()

class BasePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        #label_bkgr = tk.Label(self, image=controller.bkgr_image)
        #label_bkgr.place(x=0,y=0)  # Center label w/image.
        pass


class Home(BasePage):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        home_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=50, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
        home_frame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='True')

        p1 = tk.PanedWindow(home_frame, orient='horizontal', bd=4, relief='raised', bg='#595959', width=1500)
        p1.pack()
        home = tk.Button(p1, text='Home', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(home)
        about = tk.Button(p1, text='About Us', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(about)
        academic = tk.Button(p1, text='Academic', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(academic)
        facilities = tk.Button(p1, text='Facilities', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(facilities)
        student_life = tk.Button(p1, text='Student Life', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(student_life)
        contact = tk.Button(p1, text='Contact', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(contact)
        admin_portal = tk.Button(p1, text='Admin Portal', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(admin_portal)
        staff_portal = tk.Button(p1, text='Staff Portal', height=1, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='center')
        p1.add(staff_portal)

        l = tk.Label(home_frame, text="Fact of the Day")
        l.pack()
        T = tk.Text(home_frame, height=5, width=52, font='Arial')
        T.pack()
        Fact = """A man can be arrested in Italy for wearing a skirt in public."""
        T.insert(tk.END, Fact)

    def show_frame(self,container):
        frame = self.frames[container]
        frame.tkraise()
```

Comment: When using frames over each other with a controller you shouldn't use `frame.pack()`, but instead you should use `frame.grid(row=1, column=1)`. I don't know if that is related to your problem

Comment: Please post a complete app, ideally a minimal version.